# can't find PictureBox in Toolbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't find PictureBox in my visual studio's toolbox, however it's checked in tools>choose toolbox item.

Is there any solution for using it without uninstalling and installing VS again?
Can i use any other tools instead of PictureBox for inserting image uploading operation in a website?

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: PictureBox is for Winforms not ASP.Net, correct?

Comment: ASP .NET doesn't have a PictureBox, that is for WinForms. in ASP .NET you would just use `<img src=.../>`.

Comment: As above, you will probably be wanting to use the Image, and ImageButton controls

Comment: /search?q=image+uploading+asp.net

Comment: You mean that i can not use it in website design? excuse me if my question is so naive! i'm beginner in asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

There is no PictureBox in asp.net. Use the "Image", which you will find under the "Standard" controls.

Beware though, "Image" is a "big" component. If you just want to display an image, use the plain HTML [img-Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp).

For uploading, use the FileUpload control.

Comment: Thanks. You give me the clue! I will search about FileUpload control.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ASP fileUpload, and display the uploaded file in an ASP image control.

## HTML (ASPX)

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

## Code behind

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs("filename")
```

Comment: Thanks. You give me the clue! I will search about FileUpload control.

Comment: Edited my answer, don't use the HTML fileinput, use the ASP fileupload control instead. Drag it onto your form.

Answer (score 0):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is a good library for uploading all kinds of files (including images) to websites.

As people have said in the comments, you can't use WinForms controls in ASP.NET

Or use a simple

```
<input type="file">
```

Comment: Thanks. You give me the clue! I will search about FileUpload control.